# Two lines on one graph

Tags: r

How can I draw two lines on one graph.  Here is my code:

```
data <- read.csv(file='best_duty_distribution.csv', header = TRUE, sep = " ")

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data, aes(x=p1_b, y=b1, color = "red")) +
  geom_line(data, aes(x=p1_b, y=f1, color = "blue"))
```

But I get the error:

```
Ошибка: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval
```

This code works fine, but draw only one line:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=p1_b, y=b1)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

**Update:**

Example of data:

```
> head(data, 4)
  p1_b p2_b p3_b b1 f1 b2 f2 b3  f3  X
1    0    0    0  0 40  0 20  0 160 NA
2    0    0    1  0 40  0 20  4 152 NA
3    0    0    2  0 40  0 20  8 144 NA
4    0    0    3  0 40  0 20 12 136 NA
```

Comment: A side-note: in `aes` you _map_ different aesthetics to _variables_ in your data (e.g. map colour to a grouping variable in your data). If you wish to _set_ a value (e.g. set colour to "red"), do so outside `aes`. See e.g. the rather weird legend in @Harpals plot.

Comment: Where can I find the description of 'aes'? It is a magic for me now. I have tried to google it, but didn't find something essential

Comment: The [**official help texts**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/) can sometimes be rather thin. Especially for such a central function as `aes`. One way to get a better feeling for its use is to work through the output of the examples (e.g. for some relevant `geom`s). Also check this nice [**tutorial**](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/).

Comment: Thanks. I was searching in R-land documentation...

Comment: Another one: http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2. I belive "The Anatomy of a Plot" gives you quick feeling for the `ggplot` paradigm and terminology. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom`s expect the first unnamed argument to be the mapping and the second the data. Either name your arguments or reverse them:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=data, aes(x=p1_b, y=b1, color = "red")) +
  geom_line(data=data, aes(x=p1_b, y=f1, color = "blue"))
```

or,

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x=p1_b, y=b1, color = "red"), data) +
  geom_line(aes(x=p1_b, y=f1, color = "blue"), data)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the first version of your answer was better :) It was easier to understand where is my mistake

Comment: Note that if you want a red line and a blue line, `color` must be outside `aes`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your data looks like, but this draw two lines :

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:15, x=rnorm(15), y=rnorm(15))
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x="a", y="x")) + geom_line(colour="red")
p <- p + geom_line(data=df, aes_string(x="a", y="y"), colour="blue")
p
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for small plots, you can build the plot yourself:

```
> df <- data.frame(x=1:6,y1=1:6,y2=2:7)
> ggplot(df, aes(x)) + geom_line(aes(y=y1,colour="blue")) + geom_line(aes(y=y2,colour="red"))
```

This makes:

[image]

You can also melt the data:

```
> library(reshape)
> df2 <- melt(df,id="x")
> ggplot(df2, aes(x=x,y=value,colour=variable)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Check you legend: a good reason not to _set_ values for an aesthetic inside `aes`. Inside `aes` you _map_ aesthetics to a variable in your data set.